# Chrome Browser Version In Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I have set up one **Selenium Grid** with **one Hub in Ubuntu Server** and **one Node in Ubuntu Desktop**. **Google Chrome** version on **Node** is `Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. And my python code for creating session is

```
# Add Chrome options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.set_capability("browserVersion", "85.0.4183.83")
options.set_capability("platformName", "linux")

# Open a remote browser Session
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://192.168.56.7:4444/wd/hub',
    options=options
)
```

But when I am passing `options.set_capability("browserVersion", "85.0.4183.83")` it gives error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 85.0.4183.83, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-extensions], extensions: []}, platformName: linux, version: }

But without that line, it works absolutely fine.

Also, like to know if there is any option of passing only the Major version of the browser like `85` without passing the exact version number like `85.0.4183.83`.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: the case is chrome do not let you download previous versions. You can either stick to that current version. But once you recreate that virtual machine it will install the latest chrome. Another problem is the latest chrome is not always compatible with the chromedriver. You can use firefox instead which I think is more stable.

Comment: @slackingslacker thank you for the reply. so you are saying that it is due to the latest release it is creating the issue?

Comment: eventually one you chrome is updated, the chromedriver varies from version to version. See this [link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) . For firefox, the [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) has more range of compatibility for browser versions.

Comment: And is there any way to pass only the major version of the browser without matching the complete version?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any. You can check [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)

Comment: The same result shows when passing `browserVersion` in Firefox as well.

`options.set_capability('browserVersion', '79.0')`
or
`options.set_capability('browserVersion', 'latest')`

Comment: lets go back to the original post, why do you need the browser version?

Comment: When I want to check the APP on a specific browser version.

Comment: I see, so what you want is to automate the testing using different browser. Not sure though if it is possible or there are settings to do that. What browser is currently installed to the machine is what the selenium uses and is controlled by the webdriver that you use.

Comment: You can check this - https://dzone.com/articles/desired-capabilities-in-selenium-testing-with-exam

Comment: Nice! though I still cannot see the browserVersion

Comment: Search `desired_capabilities['browser_version'] = browser_version` in the page. I have tried browser_version as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220509/discussion-between-slackingslacker-and-himadri-ganguly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. As the version information is not passed on to the **HUB** it is cannot verify the version information. So have to pass **nodeConfig** when connecting to **HUB** from the **NODE**.

**node-config.json**

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "browserVersion": "79.0"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "browserVersion": "85.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then start the connection using

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://[HUB-IP]:4444/grid/register/ -nodeConfig node-config.json
```

Now passing `options.set_capability("browserVersion", "85.0")` will work. So using this you can now specify which **OS**, **Browser**, and **Browser Version** you want to test on.

Ref:- https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/grid_3/setting_up_your_own_grid/